# Node.js 405 (Method Not Allowed) and Column cannot be null MySQL

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js, fetch-api

I'm trying to post data to my database. I have two problems.
Problem 1:
I get a response that method is not allowed. I've put the images below

[enter image description here][1]

The second problems I have is that my data keeps returning null when trying to insert the user's comments into MySQL database:

Here's the error:
[enter image description here][2]

Here's my code:

superhero.html:

```
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <h1> Welcome To Chatroom</h1>

        <div class="card mb-2" style="width: 38rem;" id="output">
    
        </div>

        <form class="inputs" id="form" name="form">
            <textarea class="comments" id="comments" placeholder="what's on your mind?" name="comments" ></textarea>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitbtn">send</button>
        </form>

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/superhero.js"></script>
    <script src="/reload/reload.js"></script>

</body>
```

superhero.js

```
const output = document.getElementById('output');
const username = document.querySelector('#username');
const date = document.querySelector('#date');
const submitbtn = document.querySelector('#submitbtn');
const commentOutput = document.querySelector('#message');
const form = document.querySelector('#form');
const comments = document.querySelector('#comments')

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(e);


    let formMessage = new FormData(form);

    formMessage.append('api-key', 'myApiKey');


    fetch('http://localhost:5502/superhero', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(formMessage)

    }).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response)
        return response.text();
    }).then(function(text) {
        console.log(text);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
})
```

index.js

```
router.post("/superhero", function(req, res) {

    const user = req.user;
    const comments = req.body.comments;

    sqlDatabase.query("INSERT INTO comments (user_id, comments) VALUES (?, ?)", [user, comments],
        function(error, results, fields) {
            if (error) throw error;
            console.log(results);
            console.log(error)
        });
})


router.get("/superhero", authenticationMiddleware(), function(req, res, err) {

    sqlDatabase.query("SELECT users.username, comments.comments, comments.date FROM users INNER JOIN comments ON users.user_id=comments.user_id",
        function(error, results, fields) {
            if (error) throw error;
            res.render('superhero');
            console.log(results);
        })

})
```

I'm a noob by the way. Been struggling on this. Any help would be appreciated.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nG7Tq.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlgOp.png

Comment: Did you include authentication information in the GET request?
Did you try to print out the body of the request?

Comment: The user = req.user is from passport auth. The only info user is sending from html is the comments.

No I didn't include auth in GET request. You referring to printing out from the route.get()?

Comment: I'm actually getting undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally fixed the problem. I changed this line
from:

```
body: JSON.stringify(formMessage)
```

to

```
 body: JSON.stringify({ comments: comments.value })
```